# Is there a practical limit on the number of PostgreSQL TYPES?

Tags: postgresql

We are using Postgresql 9.6  in an application where we are considering using the TYPES system to extend new object types

The system would start with 10-20 types and then users would have a UI to create new types, probably composite types.

Question - is there a practical limitation on the number of TYPES?

From a system design alternative perspective we *could* use MongoDB and JavaScript objects which would give us more expressiveness - it would also require us to support MongoDB which is not our core expertise or we could go in other directions like using F# type system but that is going astray from this question....

and we believe the PG types will give us better mileage....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Practical, no. All internal types are represented by an [`oid`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html). That's an unsigned four-byte integer.

```
SELECT oid, *
FROM pg_type;
```

PostgreSQL uses OIDs as an internally unique ID. When you exhaust them you're out.

Creating 1,000 types: NOT A PROBLEM.
Creating 4.3 billion types: **PROBLEM.**

### Update

As a side note, I don't see how you can expose the types usefully to a user. PostgreSQL has a type [`jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html). It's indexable and stored as binary, like Mongo's BSON. I would be using that.